# parse command line values

Tags: bash, text-parsing

I'm having a problem with my script and i can't seem to see where the problem occurs.

```
rules=$(echo "$result" | grep '^[[:space:]]\{2\}[0-9]\|^\*' | sed 's/^.//' | \
        awk '{ x = $0 "\n" x } END { printf "%s", x }' | awk '{print $1}')
numRules=$(echo "$rules" | wc -l)
```

This is my script for the data below this would be the value of `$result`

```
ID Action Category From Hits 
---------------------------- 
100 deny trial1     herb 0
200 deny trial2222 herb.patrick 0
300 deny triaaaals herb.patrick.hernandez 0
```

My goal is to be able to get the id which is 100, 200, 300 to be placed in `$rules` and for me to be able to get the total count of ids for this example: `3` would be the right return for `$numRules`.

```
$rules= 100 200 300
$numRules = 3
```

Comment: Hi I edited the question and added the results i would like to have. I hope it helps. 
I'm not really sure if its by tabs or spaces but that's how the command line returns when i issue a command to output that data. @Cyrus

Answer (score 1, accepted):

With GNU grep and an array:

```
rules=($(grep -o '^[0-9]\+' file))
numRules=${#rules[@]}

echo ${rules[@]}
echo $numRules
```

Output:

```
100 200 300
3
```